# Adding a cordova plugin to Ionic 2

Tags: cordova, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I used [this](https://github.com/PDF417/pdf417-phonegap) plugin in ionic v1, workd fine. But Im not sure how to add it to Ionic 2

Cant build the project because it cant find cordova

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';


@Component({
    selector: 'page-scan-vehicle',
    templateUrl: 'scan-vehicle.html'
})
export class ScanVehiclePage {

    constructor(public platform: Platform, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {}

    public scan () {
        // open scanner
        // save results
        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
            cordova.plugins.pdf417Scanner.scan()
        });
    }

}
```

Enev in [this](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2016/02/add-barcode-scanning-functionality-to-your-ionic-2-app/) example they are doing the same.  But how would it work if it does not find cordova, I mean cordova is only added once built isnt it??

Comment: if you know that cordova exists on runtime, try with something like (<any>cordova).plugins.pdf4157Scanner.scan(); that will work with TS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main difference of your code and the example that you gave us is this one:

**Example**

app/pages/home/home.**js**

Your code (I would guess that you used ionic-cli to generate the page)

scan-vehicle-page.**ts**

**Try with this**:

```
(<any>cordova).plugins.pdf4157Scanner.scan();
```

That is a workaround to avoid issues with typescript, because **cordova** doesn't exists on that scope, but you know that it exists on runtime.

Comment: I guess its the same than adding this after all imports : declare var cordova:any;

Comment: @Harry yes, is the same.